# Javascript setTimeout function issue or callback issue

Tags: javascript, loops, callback, settimeout, setinterval

I have 2 test pages http://www.emoceanstudios.com.au/test.php, and http://www.emoceanstudios.com.au/test2.php, here is the relevant script for the first page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function slide_out(){
    $('#red-block').animate({
        marginLeft: -278
    }, 500);
    $('#yellow-block').animate({
        marginTop: -316
    }, 500);    
    $('#gray-block').animate({
        marginLeft: 278
    }, 500, function(){
        $('#three-color-container').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('#three-color-container-new').fadeIn(500, function() {
                window.setTimeout(function(){slide_in()}, 4000);
            });
        }); 
    }); 
}
function slide_in(){
    $('#three-color-container-new').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#three-color-container').fadeIn(500, function(){
            $('#red-block, #yellow-block, #gray-block').animate({
                marginLeft: 0,
                marginTop: 0
            }, 500, function() {
                window.setTimeout(function(){slide_out()}, 4000);
            });
        });
    });
}

window.setTimeout(function(){slide_out()}, 4000);
</script>
```

Now the red yellow gray color blocks slide like this: out, in, out, in, out and then flash(which is not what i want), only work for two and a half loops. If I set the timer from 4000 to 6000, it works at most 3 loops, and then breaks also.

I want it to be out, in, out, in, out, in, out, in, out, in, out, in, out, in, out, in...... forever I guess the problem might be in the setTimeout function. But someone suspects this is because the three animate call the next function three times, so I modified and created the second page, put the three animates in a function then callback the next function, here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function slide_out(){
    block_out(callback);
}
function slide_in(){
    $('#three-color-container-new').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#three-color-container').fadeIn(500, function(){
            $('#red-block, #yellow-block, #gray-block').animate({
                marginLeft: 0,
                marginTop: 0
            }, 500, function() {
                window.setTimeout(function(){slide_out()}, 4000);
            });
        });
    });
}
function block_out(callback){
    $('#red-block').animate({
        marginLeft: -278
    }, 500);
    $('#yellow-block').animate({
        marginTop: -316
    }, 500);    
    $('#gray-block').animate({
        marginLeft: 278
    }, 500);    
    callback();
}
function callback(){
    $('#three-color-container').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $('#three-color-container-new').fadeIn(500, function() {
            window.setTimeout(function(){slide_in()}, 4000);
        });
    }); 
}
window.setTimeout(function(){slide_out()}, 4000);
</script>
```

Now it becomes work for 4-5 loops, and then breaks again.

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: i see this problem in all browsers

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle pointing the issue.  Will be easy to share and access it.

Comment: i just test your pages on Chrome v28,and it works fine.

Comment: After sometime you page is collapsed with the fadin and out div.  you noticed?

Comment: @AhmedAli have you waited for half a minute